# When I run the following script, I get an error "Python has stopped working". What is the reason?

Tags: pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class Browser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Simple Browser")
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://google.com"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

app = QApplication([])
window = Browser()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I do not know the reason for the error at all.

Is the reason for the error from the side of pyqt5 or the problem from `python.exe`?

Comment: Run the code in a command-window (i.e. not an IDE) so you can see the Python traceback and/or Qt messages. The problem is probably caused by missing imports, since the code itself has no errors. Did you install [PyQtWebEngine](https://pypi.org/project/PyQtWebEngine/)?

Comment: No, I tried all these, I get the same error

Comment: That makes no sense. If you really did that, you would not see that error. Open up a python interpreter and test those import statements one by one. Then see if you can create a QApplication. Then test all the other lines one by one until you find the one that causes the problem. This isn't rocket science - it just needs some simple trial and error debugging.